# Create changelogs for reprepro debian repository

Tags: ubuntu, deb, debian-packaging

We are hosting a repository with deb files for distributing updates and components of our software. Now I would like to see changelogs in package managers like Muon or Discover.

I found that I can add a `Changelogs: URL` entry in conf/distributions but it seems to require a somewhat complex directory structure:

```
Changelogs

The Changelogs field tells the client where to find changelogs, for example, Debian uses:

Changelogs: https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/@CHANGEPATH@_changelog

The value for @CHANGEPATH@ is:

    if the package is from a component (e.g. main) this is the first part otherwise it is omitted,
    the first letter of source package name, except if the source package name starts with 'lib' in which case it will be the first four letters.
    The complete source package name.
    the complete name again and
    the source version. 

The first (if present), second, third and fourth part are separated by a slash ('/') and between the fourth and fifth part is an underscore ('_').

The special value 'no' is available for this field indicating that changelogs are not provided.
```

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#Changelogs

I have the impression this is not supported by/part of `reprepro`. Are there other tools that allow extracting the changelog from a .deb file and adding it to a folder with the correct structure?